# how to get values which is inserted in a cell of lwc datatable

Tags: lightning-web-components, datatable

```html
<template>
    <table class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered"
        aria-labelledby="element-with-table-label other-element-with-table-label">
        <thead>
            <tr class="slds-line-height_reset">
                <th class="" scope="col">
                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="Student Name">Student Name</div>
                </th>
                <th class="" scope="col">
                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="Roll Number">Roll Number</div>
                </th>
                <th class="" scope="col">
                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="Marks">Marks</div>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <template for:each={students} for:item="student">
                <tr class="slds-hint-parent" key={student.Id} onrowselection={handleSelect}>
                    <td data-label="Student Name">
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="Name">{student.name}</div>
                    </td>
                    <td data-label="Roll Number">
                        <lightning-input data-id={student.Id} type="number" name="rollNumber" onchange={handleChange} value={student.rollNo}></lightning-input>
                    </td>
                    <td data-label="Marks">
                        <lightning-input data-id={student.Id} type="number" name="Marks" onchange={handleChange} value={student.marks}></lightning-input>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </template>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Save" title="Selected Records" onclick={getSelectedRecords}></lightning-button>
</template>
```

```js
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';

export default class DatatableWithInputFields extends LightningElement {
    @track students = [
        { 'name': 'Minku', 'Id': 1, 'rollNo': '', 'marks': '' },
        { 'name': 'Vikram', 'Id': 2, 'rollNo': '', 'marks': '' },
        { 'name': 'Krishna', 'Id': 3, 'rollNo': '', 'marks': '' }
    ]
    handleChange(event) {
        let selected = this.template.querySelector('lightning-input');
        let names = selected.getAttribute('name');
        let dataId = selected.getAttribute('data-id');
        console.log(selected);  
        console.log(names);
        console.log(dataId);
    }
    getSelectedRecords() {
       
    }
    handleSelect(event){
        console.log(event. Target);
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in the [`lightning-input` specs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input/specification), the `label` attribute is required, so you must define it. If the label shouldn't be showed, you can levarage the `variant` attribute using `label-hidden` as value.

Instead of saving the Id of the record, you could store its index (provided by [`for:index`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/reference-directives.html?q=for:index#forcolonindexindex) directive) in a dataset property. This way you could easily access to the right element of the array.
If you store the field name too, the `handleChange` method could dynamically set it using the [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) (i.e. `object[fieldName] = something;`)

In the `handleChange` method you searched for the first `lightning-input` using querySelector, but it won't return the changed one. You don't need to search for it, since a reference to the right element is already hold by [`event.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) property.
Then, to get the value of a `data-*` attribute, you should use the [`dataset` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset), i.e. `event.currentTarget.dataset.index`.
Please note that the attribute should be in kebab case (dash-separated) (i.e. `data-field-name`), but when you need to access to that property in JS, it should be converted to camelCase (so `dataset.fieldName`).
Each of these attributes will always be a string, so sometimes you may need to convert it to the right data type.
The same goes for the value of a `lightning-input` element, even if it has `type="number"`. You could check it with `console.log(typeof event.detail.value);`. To convert the value to a number you could use the [unary plus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus).

These advices translates to the following code:
**HTML**

```html
<template>
    <table class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered" aria-labelledby="element-with-table-label other-element-with-table-label">
        <thead>
            <tr class="slds-line-height_reset">
                <th scope="col">
                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="Student Name">Student Name</div>
                </th>
                <th scope="col">
                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="Roll Number">Roll Number</div>
                </th>
                <th scope="col">
                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="Marks">Marks</div>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <template for:each={students} for:item="student" for:index="index">
                <tr class="slds-hint-parent" key={student.Id} onrowselection={handleSelect}>
                    <td data-label="Student Name">
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="Name">{student.name}</div>
                    </td>
                    <td data-label="Roll Number">
                        <lightning-input label="Roll Number" variant="label-hidden" type="number" data-index={index} data-field-name="rollNo" onchange={handleChange} value={student.rollNo}></lightning-input>
                    </td>
                    <td data-label="Marks">
                        <lightning-input label="Marks" variant="label-hidden" type="number" data-index={index} data-field-name="marks" onchange={handleChange} value={student.marks}></lightning-input>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </template>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="slds-size_full slds-var-m-top_medium slds-grid slds-grid_align-center">
        <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Save" title="Selected Records" onclick={getSelectedRecords}></lightning-button>
    </div>
</template>
```

**JS**

```js
handleChange(event) {
    // the index of the changed element
    const index = +event.currentTarget.dataset.index;
    console.log(index);
    // which field has changed
    const fieldName = event.currentTarget.dataset.fieldName;
    console.log(fieldName);
    // set the new value
    this.students[index][fieldName] = event.detail.value === '' ? null : +event.detail.value;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.students[index]));
}
```